# Scraping and stripping off child tags python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have following code structure from a website I wanna scrape.

```
<span class="blk">Society/Project: <b>Sai Sparsh</b></span>
      <i class="blk">
         Built-up  Area: <b>1005 Sq.Ft.</b> 
             @ <i class="WebRupeesmall b mr_5 f14">Rs.</i>6109/sq.ft</i>
```

I am already scraping few data by the following code

```
   properties = soup.findAll('a', title=re.compile('Bedroom'))
for eachproperty in properties:
 print today,","+"http:/"+ eachproperty['href']+",", eachproperty.string+"," +",".join(re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*)'", eachproperty['onclick']))
```

and my output is

```
2013-09-05 ,http://Residential-Apartment-Flat-in-Velachery-Chennai South-3-Bedroom-bhk-for-Sale-spid-E10766779, 3 Bedroom, Residential Apartment in Velachery,E10766779,9952946340,,Dealer,Bala
```

So for the above defined HTML sturcture I am trying to strip and get the output as follows

```
Sai Sparsh, 1005 Sq.Ft, 6109/sq.ft
```

and attach it to the already generating output(mentioned above). I have been breaking my head to navigate down the tree and use REGEX for it.

**Update**

Here is what I tried with the code

```
cname = soup.findAll('span', {'class':'blk'})
pmoney = soup.findAll('i',{'class':'blk'})
for eachproperty in cname:
 for each in pmoney:
  tey = re.sub('(\s{2,})', ' ', eachproperty.text)[17:]
 ting = re.sub('([0-9,\s]*)', ' ', each.text)
 print tey + ting
```

And my output is

```
Rams Jai Vignesh Built-up  Area: 1050 Sq.Ft. @ Rs.5524/sq.ft
Shrudhi Homes Built-up  Area: 1050 Sq.Ft. @ Rs.5524/sq.ft
Ashtalakshmi Homes Built-up  Area: 1050 Sq.Ft. @ Rs.5524/sq.ft
Raj Flats Built-up  Area: 1050 Sq.Ft. @ Rs.5524/sq.ft
```

But I want my output to not have 'Built-up Area:' ,' @ ', ' Rs '.
So it should be just

```
Rams Jai Vignesh ,1050  ,5524
 Shrudhi Homes   ,1050 , 5524
```

Comment: Regex? NO! http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't just use `text` property:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

soup = Soup("""<span class="blk">Society/Project: <b>Sai Sparsh</b></span>
      <i class="blk">
         Built-up  Area: <b>1005 Sq.Ft.</b>
             @ <i class="WebRupeesmall b mr_5 f14">Rs.</i>6109/sq.ft</i>""")

print re.sub('(\s{2,})', ' ', soup.text)
```

prints:

```
Society/Project: Sai Sparsh Built-up Area: 1005 Sq.Ft. @ Rs.6109/sq.ft
```

FYI, `re.sub` is here to prettify the string, since there are multiple spaces etc.

UPD: here's the scraper script for you:

```
import re
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.99acres.com/property-in-velachery-chennai-south-ffid").read()
soup = Soup(html)

re_digit = re.compile('(\d+)')
for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'sT_disc grey'}):
    try:
        project = div.find('span').find('b').text.strip()
    except:
        project = 'No project'
    area = re.findall(re_digit, div.find('i', {'class': 'blk'}).text.strip())

    print ", ".join([project] + area)
```

Comment: you are directly giving the input. But I wanna use soup.findAll function to parse through the website the select those `span` with class `blk` and so on . Hope I am clear.

Comment: Sure, when you've found the span element, just take a `text` from it. It gives a text without the html tags inside.

Comment: So I will have to use two soup.findAll in total to scrape for `<i>` also right?? is it possible to scrape through in one line and assign it to single variable. Otherwise I would have to use two variable and join them. Am I clear?

Comment: @Venky could show your code so I can see how are you using bs?

Comment: I tried this

`ting = re.sub('( Built-up  Area: | Sq\.Ft\. @ Rs\.)', ', ', each.text).replace('/sq.ft', '')`

But  output still has `Sai Sarran, 1050 Sq.Ft.  @ Rs.5524`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36889/discussion-between-venky-and-alecxe)